# System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error on specific hosting account

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce, system.net

I have been facing a very difficult issue and I'm not able to figure out what's wrong?

I am working on a nopCommerce 3.20 which is built upon ASP.net MVC.

I am trying to call one of my custom function from another function.

This works fine on my development machine, on my test server and on few other hosting account. However, the same doesn't work on one of the hosting account, no matter whatever we do! We checked file permissions, they are all fine. The internal functions works fine everywhere else except this particular hosting account where needed.

I get following error trying to run this...

```
System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found. at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
```

What could be wrong here?

Comment: It sounds like it could be an IIS issue - virtual directory pointing to the wrong directory, or something. Just something to double check...

Comment: Right, it was the issue with that particular hosting account. We requested support and it was fixed in less than 30 minutes. Thanks to SmarterASP http://www.Smarterasp.net/index?r=100080050 for their quick support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with particular hosting account. It was not supported to call temp url within web application. - we contacted support, and they resolved the issue in less than half an hour.

If you're having this kind of issue, make sure to ask your hosting company for support.